# Keep the same style of a spreadsheet when exporting in excel

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

With this script I could export a spreadsheet to a excel file keeping formulas and a specific range that I need.

But I need also to keep the style of the spreadsheet like colors, row height, text style...

What to add then to the code below?

```
 function downloadXLS_GUI() {
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var nSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(sh.getName()+": copy");
      var numCols = 10;
      var d = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),numCols);
      nSheet.getSheets()[0].getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),numCols).setValues(d.getValues());
      ["A3", "C3", "F3", "G3", "H3", "F5", "G5", "H5"].forEach(a1Notation => {
        var sourceFormulas = sh.getRange(a1Notation).getFormulas();
        nSheet.getRange(a1Notation).setFormulas(sourceFormulas);
      });
      var URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+nSheet.getId()+'/export?format=xlsx';
      var htmlOutput = HtmlService
                      .createHtmlOutput('<a href="'+URL+'">Clicca qui per scaricare</a>')
                      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
                      .setWidth(380)
                      .setHeight(160);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Scarica Allegato 2 in Excel');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

###### Update 2

For copying styles between different sheets you can use this method.

```
function downloadXLS_GUI() {
  const numCols = 10
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const nSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(sh.getName() + ": copy");

  const o_range = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), numCols)
  const c_range = nSheet.getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), numCols)

  // Get the values and styles from the original
  const v = o_range.getValues()
  const b = o_range.getBackgrounds()
  const c = o_range.getFontColors()
  const f = o_range.getFontSizes()
  // Set the values and styles to the copy
  c_range.setValues(v)
  c_range.setBackgrounds(b)
  c_range.setFontColors(c)
  c_range.setFontSizes(f)
  const formulaA1Notation = ["A3", "C3", "F3", "G3", "H3", "F5", "G5", "H5"]
  formulaA1Notation.forEach(a1Notation => {
    var sourceFormulas = sh.getRange(a1Notation).getFormulas();
    nSheet.getRange(a1Notation).setFormulas(sourceFormulas);
  });
  var URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + nSheet.getId() + '/export?format=xlsx';
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showDialog(
      HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutput(`<a href="${URL}" target="_blank">Download</a>`)
    )
}
```

---

Why not use the [`copy`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname) method?

> Copies the spreadsheet and returns the new one.

Instead of copying a certain range, you copy it all and get rid of what you don't need.

For example:

###### `Code.gs`

```js
function downloadXLS_GUI() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .copy("new_copy")
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
  const numRows = 10;
  sheet
    .getRange(1, numRows + 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
    .clear()
  const URL = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=xlsx`;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showDialog(
      HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutput(`<a href="${URL}" target="_blank">Download</a>`)
    )
}
```

###### Documentation

- [`clear()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#clear)

Comment: Cause I need to export only the spreadsheet from column A to column J and keep the formulas only in the cells: A3, C3, F3, G3, H3, F5, G5, H5 as my code on top.

Comment: Could you share a sanitized copy of your spreadsheet? It would make it easier to visualize what you need.

Comment: The spreadsheet use sensitive data. I need only that I cannot lose the formulas as the code on top, but keep the style.

Comment: When a `copy` is performed, also the formulas are copied. In the way you are doing it, you are only copying the values. To transfer also the styles, you  will need something like the [`Range.copyTo(destination, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options) first copy the format only, and after perform the operation of your script, this will be valid?

Comment: I updated my question check if it works for you.

Comment: And so what is the final code?

Comment: Just add the two lines to your original script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242857/discussion-between-gavis-and-emel).

Comment: I updated my answer,  check if now is working for you

Comment: Hello and so I need the final code to test (your code + my code)

Comment: Full code in the answer. Before, the answer was already there. You just need to put in a little effort.

Comment: As you can see the screen https://imgur.com/a/4ZQIZIE your code not works, there are some difference from the sheet then the excel (like row heights, wrap text...)

Comment: Please, provide a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DWuhCy7k4XhOI10nmQFOwLQe8RarU6XVFl6gD00UXx4/edit#gid=784952645

Comment: In addition I am showing you the desidered output in excel https://imgur.com/a/JBJxFnk

Comment: any update for the question?

Comment: How about if you use the first method I proposed but in addition to copy the data you want, you use `sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent()` and then make the copy in your original script? [This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) will keep the formatting and copy only what you need. Let me know your results